# Can you run programs (i.e photoshop, illustrator) with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, executable

I was wondering if you could use Ruby to control other programs on your computer. (Like photoshop, illustrator, iTunes, etc) To either start running or to do something more specific?

Comment: In OS X you can using apple script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute external program in ruby and wait for its execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649508/execute-external-program-in-ruby-and-wait-for-its-execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, you can do `system("open -a iTunes -W")` (or the backticks version if you prefer). `-W` makes sure that the execution is blocked until the callee exits.

As for controlling the program, on OS X it is fairly straight-forward with `RubyCocoa` (which unfortunately is not supporting 10.11 at the moment). Docs can be found here: https://rubycocoa.github.io.